# d3.js ordinal axis is not updated correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I created a simple, updatedable d3.js bar chart.
Except for the x-axis, it works fine.

When I remove bars from the chart, the corresponding axis labels are not removed.

[image: initial bars]
[image: removed bars first time with wrong axis]

But when I remove bars for the second time, the labels of the bars that were removed in the first run are removed from the axis.

[image: removed bard second time with correct axis]

What is happening here, and why?

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vACua/4/

The js code would be the following:

```
    var BarChart = function (config) {

    var data,
    svg,
    xScale,
    yScale,
    yAxis,
    xAxis;

   svg = d3.select('#' + config.targetElement).append('svg');

    svg.attr("width", config.width + config.margin.left + config.margin.right)
        .attr("height", config.height + config.margin.top + config.margin.bottom)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + config.margin.left + "," + config.margin.top + ")");

    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal();
    yScale = d3.scale.linear();

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickSize(-config.height, 0).tickPadding(6);
    svg.append('g').classed('x-axis-group axis', true);

    svg.append("g")
        .classed("x axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);


    // All methods and members defined here are public
    return {
        setData: function (newData) {
            data = newData;
            this.updateChart();
        },
        updateChart: function () {
            var xDomain = data.map(function (d) {
                return d.name;
            }),
                yDomain = data.map(function (d) {
                    return d.value;
                });



            xScale.domain(xDomain)
                .rangeRoundBands([config.margin.left, config.width], 0.05);

            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })])
                .range([config.height, 0]);


            xAxis.scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickSize(-config.height, 0)
                .tickPadding(6);

            var dataSections = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
                .data(data, function (d) {
                return d.name;
            });


            // adding new bars
            dataSections.enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
                .append("rect")
                .attr("height", 0);

            var transition = svg.transition().duration(750);

            transition.selectAll("g.bar").select('rect')
                .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return xScale(d.name);
            })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yScale(d.value);
            })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                return height - yScale(d.value);
            });


            dataSections.exit().transition().remove();



            svg.select('.x.axis')
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr({
                transform: 'translate(0,' + (config.height) + ')'
            })
                .call(xAxis);




        }
    };
};

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


amount = 15;

function init() {
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    },
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var chart = BarChart({
        targetElement: 'foo',
        margin: margin,
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    setRandomData = function () {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
            data.push({
                name: "a" + i,
                value: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1)
            });
        }
        amount = amount - 5;

        chart.setData(data);
    }
}

init();
setRandomData();
setTimeout(setRandomData, 2000);
setTimeout(setRandomData, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have absolutely no clue why but moving

```
svg.select('.x.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr({transform: 'translate(0,' + (config.height) + ')'})
    .call(xAxis);
```

before this line:

```
var transition = svg.transition().duration(750);
```

seems to work the way you intended: http://jsfiddle.net/Y274x/